# Caffeinate pid with os.getpid()

Tags: python, macos, subprocess, python-os

I'm a beginner and I want my macOS don't sleep until the current python process has terminated. This is my code with python, I used caffeinate

```
import os
import subprocess
t=os.getpid()
subprocess.run(['caffeinate','-u','-w',t])
print("something...")
```

But it got error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davidkyan/Desktop/demo.py", line 4, in <module>
    subprocess.run(['caffeinate','-u','-w',t])
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 488, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1482, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int
```

Please help me what's wrong, its just a simple code.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by `t` which is a `int`

Try changing the code as below -

```
import os
import subprocess
t=os.getpid()
subprocess.run(['caffeinate','-u','-w',str(t)])
print("something...")
```

Comment: Thanks. But another bug occurred, the program doesn’t terminate